# Welcher Satz ist richtig?

Tags: grammaticality

> 1. Ich denke,dieses Thema ist sehr wichtig und es wäre gut,wenn die Leute diesem Thema mehr Aufmerksam schenken würde.
> 2. Ich denke,dieses Thema ist sehr wichtig und es wäre gut,wenn die Leute diesem Thema mehr Aufmerksam schenken.

Comment: Beide Sätze sind falsch.

Comment: Das Substantiv *Aufmerksam* existiert nicht. Man kann aus vielen Adjektiven mit den Endungen -heit und -keit Substantive machen.

Comment: richtig ist: _... mehr Aufmerksam**keit** schenken **würden**_ oder _Aufmerksam**keit** schenk**t**en_, wobei die erste Variante geläufiger ist.

Answer (score 2):

The first is more grammatically consistent; the second feels colloquial. Also, it should be "würden" because "Leute" is plural.

Here's an alternative formulation:

> "Ich halte dieses Thema für sehr wichtig und bin der Meinung, man sollte ihm mehr Aufmerksamkeit schenken."